# What does "se déplacer" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

How does one use the verb *se déplacer*? I got it translated as "to move," and it made sense (I saw it first in the context of hockey players moving around a rink), but I don't really understand it yet. Could someone give a few examples, maybe? I mean, it's obviously not the same as *mouvoir.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Se déplacer*, c'est aller d'un endroit (d'une « place ») à un autre.

> « Comment te déplaces-tu ? » : *"How do you move about?*". On
>   s'attend à une réponse du genre : « À pied (en cheval, en
>   voiture...) ».

L'équivalent de *se déplacer* serait *se mouvoir*, (« se mettre en mouvement ») et pas juste *mouvoir*. La différence entre les deux est essentiellement une question de niveau de langue, *se mouvoir* est d'un style beaucoup plus relevé, beaucoup moins employé dans la langue courante.

> Il y avait tellement de monde qu'on avait du mal à se déplacer/à se
>   mouvoir.

On peut aussi utiliser *se mouvoir* pour « bouger sur place ». Si je dis « j'ai du mal à me mouvoir » je peux vouloir dire que, par exemple, j'ai mal au dos et que j'ai du mal à marcher, à me lever, etc., par contre je pourrais très bien *me déplacer* en fauteuil roulant.

Dans un emploi non pronominal (c'est à dire, juste *déplacer* ou *mouvoir*) les deux sont synonymes de « bouger », *mouvoir* restant d'un niveau de langue beaucoup plus relevé, on l'utilisera plus volontiers en poésie par exemple. *Mouvoir* reste le plus souvent employé à la voie passive pour transcrire l'effet d'une impulsion sentimentale.

> Mû par un amour déçu, il s'est jeté sous un train.

---

Edit : another example (just to be on the serious side):

> Mû par la curiosité, le petit garçon souleva le couvercle de la boîte et ...

Comment: Eh bien, il est gai le dernier exemple :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I do not understand this use of *gai.* As far as I know it's like happy, cheerful, jolly? But fantastic answer. And geez, I had to say "l'utilisera" out loud a few times. That one's a tongue twister.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Indeed, that's the meaning. But, if we were to gather statistics, I guess literal uses of this word would be lost among ironic ones.

Comment: LMAO I didn't actually read the last example; I got distracted and forgot. That's so funny.

Comment: « À pied (en cheval, en voiture...) ». How do you get around? What transportation do you use? For the hockey rink players: move on ice and around the rink. The British do say "move about" for "move around" for one meaning but what do they know about ice hockey?

Answer (score 2):

déplacer is used to refer to local travel, for example, se déplacer pour aller au travail: to travel to work, to take transportation to get to work; Je me déplace en autobus: I get around [the town] on the bus. Je n'aime pas mon travail parce qu'il y a trop de déplacements. I don't like my job, there's too much travel.

Answer (score -1):

I was taught that it means, "To get away from it all." We were taught this in a travel and tourism context though.